# Visual Studio Setup Project - Retrieving a string from a TextBox Dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-deployment, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am trying to get a value from one of the text box dialogs in Visual Studio Setup Project into a custom action installer class. It seems that it doesn't like it when someone enters a string with a space in it. If a user enters a string with no spaces or quotation marks I can retrieve the string no problem. Otherwise I am getting this error:

> Exception occurred while initializing
>   the installation: 
>   System.ArgumentException: File
>   Source=localhost;Initial does not
>   exist. If this parameter is used as an
>   installer option, the format must be
>   /key=[value]

Please note that the string is a database connection and "Source=localhost;Initial" would be the *second* token, if i were to split the entire string on a space. I am clearly missing something here because I cannot imagine that this is an actual limitation of the Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You may have to surround your parameter with quotation marks, something like:

```
/connectionString="[CONNECTIONSTRING]"
```

That's just a guess, I'm basing it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28VS.71%29.aspx which suggests that values with spaces in them need to be quoted. The documentation doesn't address your situation exactly, so it's hard to tell.